# csv.writer is writing values for one key but not for all the others

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with rows of key pairs.

Let us call key, `'key'` and the different values `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, etc..

I am trying to use `csv.writer` so that it writes the row onto a file only if the value is `'b'`.

I have the following code so far:

```
csvfileR = []

with open('csvfileR.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        csvfileR.append(row)

w = open('csvfileW.csv','w')
fieldnames = ['key']
writer = csv.writer(w)
writer.writerow(fieldnames)

for i in range(len(csvfileR)):
    if csvfileR[i]['key'] == 'b':
        print (csvfileR[i]['key'])
        fields = [csvfileR[i]['key']]
        writer.writerow(fields)
```

The issue is that `writer` writes correctly when we filter for value `'a'` (`if csvfileR[i]['key'] == 'a'`) but gives a blank csv file when we filter for any other value (`if csvfileR[i]['key'] == 'b'` (or `'c'` or `'d'` etc)).

The `print` method works correctly for all values so the `Dict` is appended correctly.

Specifically, `csvfileR` contains data of my asset trades.  I want `csv.writer` to create '`csvfileW`' with trade data for only one asset in a series of different assets.

One row of `csvfileR` would look like:

`OrderedDict([('Date', '2016.09.12'), ('Name of Asset Traded', 'Facebook Stock'), ('Price purchased', '$100'), ('Price sold, '$150')`

The issue is that `csv.writer` will write if I filter out for my first asset 'Facebook Stock', but will not write if I filter out for any other asset.

So

`if csvfileR[i]['Name of Asset Traded'] == 'Facebook Stock'`

will create a CSV file correctly but,

`if csvfileR[i]['Name of Asset Traded'] == 'Apple Stock'`

or

`if csvfileR[i]['Name of Asset Traded'] == 'FedEx Stock'`

will create a blank CSV file.

However,

`print (csvfileR[i]['Name of Asset Traded'])`

will print out `'Apple'` or '`'FedEx'` each time it runs into it.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show a few lines from `csvFileR.csv` and what output you are trying to get.

Comment: Hey Martin,

I have edited my post with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I said, it would be useful if you could copy paste (exactly) some lines from your `csvFileR.csv` file, I would then be able to recreate your problem and find out what the problem might be. The code you have seems ok so the issue might be in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned consider using one single `with` to handle read and write of both files and even avoid the need of the *csvfileR* list.

```
with open('csvfileR.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('csvfileW.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    fieldnames = ['key']
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        if row['key'] == 'b':
            print (row['key'])
            fields = [row['key']]
            writer.writerow(fields)
```

However, code above seems strange as only *b* would output in first column of output csv. Likely, post does not reflect actual code. Adjust above as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.  Very silly mistake.  Did not include w.close() at the end of the code.  Code works fine now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Context manager using `with` avoids the need of `close`. In fact, you can combine both `open` in same `with` clause.